# Build 'libconfig' as a 32-bit library

Tags: c, linux, redhat, libconfig

I am trying to use the libconfig (http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/ ) for a little utility I am trying to write.  I am trying to build libconfig then copy the library file (libconfig.a) to my utility's directory.  When I build my utility I get warnings about the architecture being incompatible.  Here is one of the specific warning messages I receive.

`/usr/bin/ld: warning: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file 'libconfig.a(libconfig_la-libconfig.o)' is incompatible with i386 output`

I am building on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.10 machine (`uname -m` produces `'x86_64'`).  I tried building libconfig with the following:

`configure --disable-cxx CFLAGS='-m32' LDFLAGS='-m32'`

But unfortunately, this didn't seem to produce the correct library as I still see the same warnings.  There are other utilities that are created during the build process and all utilities share make common make directives which are specifying `CFLAGS = -m32 -Wextra -Wall -Werror -Os` and `LDFLAGS = -m32`, so I am unable to change this behavior.

I have also tried `configure --disable-cxx CFLAGS='-arch i386' LDFLAGS='-arch i386`, but this command line will not build the library.

Does anyone know how to build the libconfig as a 32-bit library to be consumed correctly.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `configure` script will ignore arguments like `CFLAGS=` when passed on the command line. You need to set them for the invocation of configure, i.e. something like:

```
env CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --disable-cxx
```

When this is done, all the symbols listed in the resulting `lib/.libs/libconfig.a` are listed with 32-bit addresses when the library is rebuilt.

Note in the configure script help output it does say:

> Some influential environment variables:

which means that they need to be environment variables, not passed in as parameters to the command

Comment: Petesh, thanks for the information.  Unfortunately, I am still unable to create the 32-bit library.  I failed to mentioned that my beloved IT dept has everyone using tsch by default, so the `evn CFLAGS-m32 LDFLAGS=-32` does not work.  I tried setting the env variable in my startup script (/.cshrc) with setenv, but that doesn't work either.  I never see the message that you indicated.  I also tried creating a  script with a `#!/bin/bash` with the command you listed above and that didn't work either.

Comment: @lordhog - since the `-m32` will also affect linking, I suggest you try passing: `env CC="gcc -m32" ./configure ...`

Comment: @BrettHale, thanks for showing me how to correctly issue the command within tsch.  Once the command was formatted correctly the configure command worked and then `make` built the correct library.  I tried both command line versions (@Petesh and @BrettHale) and both created a library that worked with my utility.  They were not binary equivalent though.  I am not sure what the differences are or how to determine that, but diff does tell me they are different.  I can't thank @BrettHale and @Petesh enough.